# Limit 1 page display only 5 data using yii

Tags: mysql, yii, limit

I have a problem regarding setting limit for specific page. For example i have 8 data. In page 1, only 5 data are allowed to display. the remaining data will display at the next page. How to make this possible to if the total data i get is from database. How to make this condition in sql??

Comment: Show some code. This will help to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is not clear what you are asking

but you can limite the row showd in gridView with `$dataProvider->pagination->pageSize`

eg:

```
   $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize=5;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
thank you for the response. i already found an answer..:)

//$i refer to total of page.

$start_from = ($i-1)*5;
$RsPermitSkvLim = RsPermitSkv::model()->findAllBySql("SELECT * FROM rs_permit_skv WHERE id_permit_info = $id_permit_info ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $start_from,5"); 
foreach($RsPermitSkvLim as $rsskvinfo) {
    //coding here.
}
```